# Adding Key Press Functionality to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal, slideshow, lightbox

thanks to all who have provided answers to questions I have had both directly and indirectly. I have seen a similar question, but it has been unanswered.

I have added W3's Lightbox Modal to my site. Cycling through the Lightbox gallery works by using the cursor to select the designated close, previous, and next buttons. However, I would like to add the following keypress functionalities: escape key=close, left arrow=prev, right arrow=next. When researching I have seen JavaScript KeyCodes (37, 39, etc) that enable these functions, but I had a tough time sticking them into the actual code. Any help is welcomed warmly. Thank you.

```js
     function openModal() {
     document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "block";
     }
     function closeModal() {
     document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "none";
     }
     var slideIndex = 1;
     showSlides(slideIndex);

     function plusSlides(n) {
       showSlides(slideIndex += n);
     }
     function currentSlide(n) {
       showSlides(slideIndex = n);
     }
     function showSlides(n) {
       var i;
       var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
       var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
       var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
       if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
       if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
       for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
         slides[i].style.display = "none";
       }
       for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
         dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
       }
       slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
       dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
       captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
       }
```

```html
     <div id="myModal" class="modal" style="display: none;">
             <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">×</span>
               <div id="center-slides">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="mySlides" style="display: none;">
                <div class="numbertext">1 / 14</div>
                <img src="OptimizedWebGraphics/People/Portfolio_People-                  
       6.jpg" alt="A sign written in chalk following a couple's love story"                   
    class="landscape-pic"></div>
            <div class="mySlides" style="display: none;">
                <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
        <img src="OptimizedWebGraphics/People/Portfolio_People-4.jpg" alt="a newly married couple embrace" class="portrait-pic"></div>
            <div class="mySlides" style="display: none;">
                <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
                <img src="OptimizedWebGraphics/People/FifthHouse_WatermarkedPhotos-65.jpg" alt="a man and woman clink wine glasses" class="landscape-pic"></div>
            <div class="mySlides" style="display: none;">
                <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
                <img src="OptimizedWebGraphics/People/Portfolio_People-8.jpg" alt="women smiling" class="landscape-pic"></div>
            <div class="mySlides" style="display: none;">
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>
          </div></div>
  <div class="caption-container">
        <p id="caption"></p></div>
      </div>
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: You don't have any dots (element with class name demo) so that line will fail     `dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";`

Comment: Thank you for your response, Axnyff. I don't plan on using the thumbnail gallery that comes with the Lightbox (which is to what I believe the demo class correlates). If that is the case can i just get rid of that line?